# Error creating mailgun web hook for both multipart and url encoded uploads

Tags: javascript, express

Im writing a web hook listener for Mailgun and after a few attempts I realized that my problem is that Mailgun can post webhook using multipart or x-www-form-urlencoded content-types.

This is my current code using Multer (which can handle multipart but cannot handle x-www-form-urlencoded) and I also tried with BodyParser (which handles x-www-form-urlencoded but doesn't handle multipart).

My question is simple: What should I do to be able to support both content type methods on my webhook listener?

```js
var express = require('express');
var multer  = require('multer');
var app = express();

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);


app.post('/parse', multer().any(), function (req, res) {
  var contentType = req.get('Content-Type');
  console.log(contentType);

  res.sendStatus(200);
});

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Listening on port %d', server.address().port);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After some research I managed to fix this using express-busboy which basically runs on top of busboy-connect and can parse both content-types.

```
var express = require('express');
var busboy = require('express-busboy');
var app = express();

busboy.extend(app, {
  upload: true,
  path: '/uploads',
  allowedPath: /./
});

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

app.post('/parse', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req);
  console.log(req.body);
  console.log(req.files);

  res.sendStatus(200);
});


var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Listening on port %d', server.address().port);
});
```